# no cifra la "ñ" cifrado

Tags: php

En el constructor añado la "Ñ" al charset pero la ignora a la hora de codificar y decodificar

¿Puede ser por la codificación interna de php? no es utf 8?

cesar.php

```
<?php

 error_reporting (0 );
/*****************************************************************************
* Nombre : Caesar.php
* Implementación del cifrado de cesar para Project-RIC. Este cifrado usa una clave de
* sustitución simple. En la actualidad existen muchos codes similares a este y el mas
* conocido se llama Rot13, el cual realiza una rotacion de 13 caracteres la cadena original.
* @copyLeft  : Project-RIC
* @package   : RiCrypt
* @author      : D-m-K, d4rk.m0nk3y@gmail.com, my.opera.com/d-m-k
/******************************************************************************/
class Caesar {
var $charset;
var $txt;
var $rot;

/*****************************************************************************
* Constructor
* Cifra la cadena pasada como parametro realizando la sustitucion
* de la cadena original la cantidad de veces definida en el parametro
* @param  $s = Cadena original
*                $n = Cantidad de rotaciones a cada letra
******************************************************************************/
public function __construct($s, $n) {
$this->charset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ";  //Definicion del charset
$this->txt    = $s;
$this->rot    = $n;
}

/*****************************************************************************
* Funcion : encode
* Cifra la cadena pasada como parametro realizando la sustitucion
* de la cadena original la cantidad de veces definida en el parametro
* @return $result = Mensaje cifrado
*****************************************************************************/
function encode(){
$result = "";                                                           //Variable donde queda el resultado
for($i=0; $i<strlen($this->txt); $i++)          //Realizo la sustitución de cada caracter
$result .= $this->rotate($this->txt{$i}, $this->rot);       //Invoco funcion que hace la rotacion
return $result;                                                         //Devuelvo la cadena Cifrada =)
}

/*****************************************************************************
* Funcion : decode
* Cifra la cadena pasada como parametro realizando la sustitucion
* de la cadena original la cantidad de veces definida en el parametro
* @return $result = Mensaje Descifrado
*****************************************************************************/
function decode(){
$result = "";                                                           //Variable donde queda el resultado
for($i=0; $i<strlen($this->txt); $i++)          //Realizo la sustitución de cada caracter
$result .= $this->rotate($this->txt{$i}, -$this->rot);      //Invoco funcion que hace la rotacion
return $result;                                                         //Devuelvo la cadena DesCifrada =)
}

/*****************************************************************************
* Funcion : rotate
* Realiza la rotacion de un caracter sobre el charset dependiendo el valor de la semilla
* de la cadena original la cantidad de veces definida en el parametro
* @param  $s = Cadena original
*                 $n = Cantidad de rotaciones
* @return  $result = Valor del nuevo caracter de acuerdo al indice
*****************************************************************************/
function rotate($c, $n){
$result = "";                                   //Texto de salida
$tamC = strlen($this->charset); //Longitud de la cadena del charset
$k = 0;                                                 //Indice para sustitucion de la cadena con el charset
$n %= $tamC;                                    //Semilla ó rotacion
$c = strtoupper($c);                    //Convierto a mayuscula el caracter
//Evaluo si el caracter en la posicion $i existe, de lo contrario dejo el caracter que esta por defecto
if(strstr($this->charset, $c)){
$k = (strpos($this->charset, $c) + $n);
if($k < 0){                                     //Evaluo que el indice sea mayor a 0
$k += $tamC;
}else
$k %= $tamC;
$result .= $this->charset{$k};  //Obtengo del charset el indice de $k, que es el nuevo valor
}else{
$result .= $c;                          //Dejo el caracter sin modificaciones
}
return $result;                                 //Devuelvo el caracter con el nuevo valor
}
}
?>
```

index.php

```
    <?php
 error_reporting (0 );
include 'Caesar.php';                                   //Incluyo la clase
$mensaje   = $_POST['mensaje'];                 //Mensaje a cifrar
$semilla   = $_POST['semilla'];                 //Semilla o cantidad de rotaciones al mensaje
$tarea     = $_POST['tarea'];                   //Boton pulsado por el usuario
$salida    = "";                                                //Variable que guarda el mensaje
//Aqui esta la magia
if($_POST && $mensaje != "" && $semilla != ""){
//CIFRADO DEL MENSAJE
if($_POST['tarea'] == "Cifrar"){
$cipher    = new Caesar($mensaje, $semilla);
$salida = $cipher->encode();
}
//DESCIFRADO DEL MENSAJE
if($_POST['tarea'] == "DesCifrar"){
$cipher    = new Caesar($mensaje, $semilla);
$salida = $cipher->decode();
}
}
?>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> .:: Implementacion de la cifra de Caesar ::. </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Caesar</h1><hr>
<!-- Datos para el cifrado -->
<form method="post">
<strong>Mensaje a cifrar / descifrar :</strong> <br>
<textarea name="mensaje" style="width:500px;border:1px solid #555"><?php echo $_POST['mensaje']; ?></textarea><br>
<strong>Semilla :</strong>
<input type="text" name="semilla" style="width:30px;border:1px solid #555" value="<?php echo $_POST['semilla']; ?>"> |
<input type="submit" name="tarea" value="Cifrar"> |
<input type="submit" name="tarea" value="DesCifrar">
</form>
<?php
//Muestro el mensaje de salida
if($salida != ""){
echo "<strong> Resultado del criptograma </strong> <br> \n";
echo "<div class='mensaje'>" . $salida . "</div>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sito user109740.. !!! te doy la bienvenida y te invito a que realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además revisa [ask] que te da información para realizar una buena pregunta y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!. Es importante modifiques el formato de tu pregunta explicando la problemática , saludos.